# Docker networking a spawned container running inside a container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file below. There is an api which I'm trying to reach via the `network-test` service which basically calls `docker run curl-test` through `docker.sock`. `curl-test` image/service basically calls curl onto the api endpoint via: `curl http://api:3000`. When I run docker compose the `curl-test` service works as expected, however the `network-test` service fails with `could not resolve host api`. My question is how do I pass in a reference to the container to the spawned container from within `network-test`?

```
version: '3'
services:
    api:
        build:
            context: api
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports: 
            - 3000:3000
    curl-test:
        image: curl-test
        build:
            context: curl-test
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on: 
            - api
        links: 
            - api
        tty: true
    network-test:
        build:
            context: network-test
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        depends_on: 
            - api
        links: 
            - api
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composed services are on their own private network and the names you have given these services, api, curl-test, and network-test, are only resolved by the dns on this network. You have spawned a container from within this network, but it is not attached to it. As the new container is not part of this network it cannot resolve the name 'API'. You can attach the container to the network to fix this problem, but only if your composed network is 'attachable', which is the default.

You can read more here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Further, it is not necessary to run the curl-test service -- it'll probably exit immediately. You're creating this at runtime, so it shouldn't be listed here.

Comment: Ah perfect! I made this project really to understand how docker networking works. `curl-test` is just to prove that the api is accessible from another container.